# Java Year in date is parseable with letters inside

Tags: java, spring

I have written my NotLenientDateEditor which extends CustomDateEditor

```
public NotLenientDateEditor(DateFormat dateFormat, boolean allowEmpty, int exactDateLength) {
    super(dateFormat, allowEmpty, exactDateLength);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
```

Now I need add one more functionality, because The Date 12.1.20asa21 is not parseable when I have javascript enabled, but when javascript is disabled, this date is parseable as 12.1.20.

Can You help me, how add functionality for not parse the year contains letters

Comment: How does Javascript being enabled change what happens within your Java code? You need to work out *exactly* what's going on here. (I suspect the difference is just that when Javascript is disabled, you're not getting on-the-fly validation.)

Comment: I am validating two times. With javascript during we write in textarea, and than after post request in java. Javascript is ok, but for stability I need validating also in java.

Comment: Okay, so the Javascript bit is effectively irrelevant. So now you can show us a short but complete program demonstrating the problem in your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

With this implementation seems to work:

```
package net.orique.stackoverflow.question11740273;

import java.text.DateFormat;

import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;

public class NotLenientDateEditor extends CustomDateEditor {

    public NotLenientDateEditor(DateFormat dateFormat, boolean allowEmpty,
            int exactDateLength) {
        super(dateFormat, allowEmpty, exactDateLength);
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    }

}
```

Class with `main` method:

```
package net.orique.stackoverflow.question11740273;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.m.yy");
        NotLenientDateEditor n = new NotLenientDateEditor(sdf, false, 7);

        n.setAsText("12.1.20"); // Ok
        n.setAsText("12.1.20asa21"); // Throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    }

}
```

Notes:

How do you instantiate `NotLenientDateEditor`? Which format do you set for DateFormat? Note the single digit for `month` and `7` for the `exactDateLength` constructor argument.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it ables file 12.1.2a (it does 12.2.02 from this and this is my problem). I initialize NotLenientEditor in this way

```
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    NotLenientDateEdtor editor = new NotLenientDateEdtor(format, false, 10);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
}
```

Comment: I tried do component in this a regex, but I do not know how to compare it, because when I would like use matches(regex) I have nullPointerException

Comment: `editor.setText('12.1.2a');` throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: it is not exactly10characters long`.

Comment: Is not possible to use DateUtils class?